# dxAutocomplete, Event `onSelectionChanged` returning wrong item as selectedItem

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular

Issue is happening only on non-unique values.

eg:
There is two item with same label/text/value. While choosing second item, **onSelectionChanged** evennt's **selectedItem** parameter contains **first item**. Which is wrong. expected *2nd* item.

Comment: will you provide more details , and code?
also you can try onValueChanged

Answer (score 0):

try onValueChanged like this :

**Html code:**

```html
  <dx-autocomplete
          placeholder="Type first name..."
          [(value)]="firstName"
          [dataSource]="names"
          (onValueChanged)="nameSelected($event)"
        >
        </dx-autocomplete>
```

**typeScript code:**

```
nameSelected(e) {
console.log(e);}
```